# Shared variable can not be distributed again after UnsetShared

Tags: parallelization, symbols

I see a weired behavior in my MM 10.3 version. Can someone reproduce it or explain what is going on? The code is easy:

```
a = RandomReal[{1, 100}, 10000000];
d = ParallelTable[a[[i]], {i, 10}];
UnsetShared[a]
```

> {a}

After that `a` is still known to the master (of course). Now I want to do the `ParallelTable` again.

```
d = ParallelTable[a[[i]], {i, 10}];
```

> Part::partd: Part specification a[[1]] is longer than depth of object.

That is strange as in the first call of `ParallelTable` MM distributes automatically. Anyhow I could do it by hand using: 
`DistributeDefinitions[a]` but the answer is `{}`. So the a is not distributed. As a consequence the result is still the same:

`d = ParallelTable[a[[i]], {i, 10}];`

> Part::partd: Part specification a[[1]] is longer than depth of object.

Only when I redo `a = RandomReal[{1, 100}, 10000000];` (which should not be necessary as `a` is still known the master kernel) I can distribute `a` again. Is there anything apart from `Distribute` and `UnsetShared` that I can do to be able to distribute `a` again?

Comment: You get the error message, but doesn't `d` still return the correct answer?  See the result [here](http://i.imgur.com/XHLsuoQ.png)

Comment: @JasonB The explanation is that using `UnsetShared` on something that has not been shared at the beginning messes up the internal bookeeping used for sharing and distributing definitions.  The solution is not to use `UnsetShared` on something that has not been previously been shared.

Comment: I am not going to tag this as a bug, but I did report it to Wolfram.  I am going to leave the decision about tagging to others (or will do it if Wolfram confirms that they consider it a bug).

Comment: @Jason B: Indeed I get the same result even though the error is issued. That is even more weired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you never set `a` as a shared variable before using `UnsetShared`.  That is, you were using `UnsetShared` in an incorrect manner.

**In short: make sure you never use `UnsetShared` on a symbol unless it was shared first!**

Mathematica in general is pretty forgiving (unlike languages like C) and won't make it possible to mess up its internal state for good (unless you explicitly poke around in its insides).  This is one of those cases when it is being less forgiving, and a single incorrect use of `UnsetShared` can induce a persistent bad state.

#### Observe what happens during correct usage

We set `a` on the main kernel.

```
In[1]:= a = 1;
```

Using `ParallelDo` automatically distributes `a`.

```
In[2]:= ParallelDo[Print[a], {4}]

(kernel 4) 1

(kernel 3) 1

(kernel 2) 1

(kernel 1) 1
```

`a` is now recorded in the list of distributed symbols.  This list is used to prevent distributing the same symbol *every single time it's used* even if its value hasn't changed.  It is an optimization measure.

```
In[3]:= Parallel`Developer`$DistributedDefinitions    
Out[3]= {Hold[a]}
```

Setting `a` as shared removes it from the list of distributed symbols to prevent bad interactions between the sharing and distribution mechanisms.  It also prevents further distribution through other means.

```
In[4]:= SetSharedVariable[a]

In[5]:= Parallel`Developer`$DistributedDefinitions    
Out[5]= {}
```

After "unsharing" `a`, it gets removed from the shared list ([`$SharedVariables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$SharedVariables.html)), and it will be available for distribution again.

```
In[6]:= UnsetShared[a]    
Out[6]= {a}
```

`ParallelDo` now does what we expect: it distributes `a` if necessary and evaluates as usual.

```
In[7]:= ParallelDo[Print[a], {4}]

(kernel 4) 1

(kernel 3) 1

(kernel 2) 1

(kernel 1) 1
```

#### Observe what happens during incorrect usage

```
In[1]:= a = 1;

In[2]:= ParallelDo[Print[a], {4}]

(kernel 4) 1

(kernel 3) 1

(kernel 2) 1

(kernel 1) 1

In[3]:= Parallel`Developer`$DistributedDefinitions
Out[3]= {Hold[a]}
```

So far so good.

But now we try to "unshare" `a` without it having been shared first.  This means that the distribution mechanism has never been disabled for `a`.  But now `UnsetShared` clears its values in the subkernels.

```
In[4]:= UnsetShared[a]
Out[4]= {a}
```

On the main kernel it appears that `a` is *already distributed*. It's still listed in `$DistributedDefinitions`. Unless its value changes on the main kernel, it won't get redistributed.  The main kernel does not know that the subkernel values of `a` are inconsistent with the main kernel values.

```
In[5]:= Parallel`Developer`$DistributedDefinitions
Out[5]= {Hold[a]}
```

Even if we tried to distribute again (which `ParallelDo` does automatically), `a` remains undefined on the subkernels.  That's because the main kernel thinks that its value is already consistent between all kernels.

```
In[6]:= ParallelDo[Print[a], {4}]

(kernel 4) a

(kernel 3) a

(kernel 2) a

(kernel 1) a
```

If you accidentally get yourself into this situation, you can reset the distribution mechanism like this:

```
In[7]:= Parallel`Developer`ClearDistributedDefinitions[]

In[8]:= ParallelDo[Print[a], {4}]

(kernel 4) 1

(kernel 3) 1

(kernel 2) 1

(kernel 1) 1
```

---

Note that `` Parallel`Developer`$DistributedDefinitions `` is not a user-settable list (it's not even a list under the hood, it just looks like it), so do not try to remove `Hold[a]` from there.

#### Finally

I am not sure if I should call this a bug because the problem is only triggered if the user makes a mistake. But it would be much better if `UnsetShared` were a little smarter and would refuse to "unshare" things that haven't already been shared.  I don't see why it couldn't do this given that `$SharedVariables` and `$SharedFunctions` exist.  I am going to send a suggestion to Wolfram Support about this.

`UnsetShared` already behaves nicely if it is given a string instead of a symbol.  `UnsetShared["a"]` will only "unshare" `a` if it has already been shared.  `UnsetShared[a]` will misbehave, as you observed.

Comment: So we have the pair of SetSharedVariable and UnsetShared. The pendant for DistributeDefinition is Parallel`Developer`ClearDistributedDefinitions[] (UnsetDefinition would be nice :)). So the thing going wrong here is actually that UnsetShared clears "a" from some "list" (it is neither $SharedVariables nor Parallel`Developer`$DistributedDefinitions) that makes ParallelTable issue the error even though "a" was not unset from the kernels.

Comment: @Eisbär The problem is simply that the two functions were not used in a pair.  The mechanism by which the problem manifests itself is not that `UnsetShared` clears `a` from a bookkeeping list.  It is that you didn't use `SetSharedVariable` so `a` never got cleared from the distributed list!  But the solution is not to try to edit the internal state, as that can very easily break things.  The solution is to always use `SetSharedVariable` and `UnsetShared` in pairs.

Comment: Something that I noticed when looking at RAM consumption. UnsetShared and Parallel`Developer`ClearDistributedDefinitions[] free the same amount of memory. However, after a Parallel`Developer`ClearDistributedDefinitions[] the memory consumption jumps up again while after UnsetShared it doesn't. In both cases the list ParallelTable makes (d) is the same. Only last mentioned procedure issues an error. How can UnsetShared free the memory and the ParallelTable after that giving still the same result?

Comment: @Szablocs: The missing bit for me was Parallel`Developer`ClearDistributedDefinitions[] as ParallelTable internally uses DistributeDefinitions for "a" and not SetSharedVariable. So UnsetShared was the only thing coming close to what I needed to free the memory after ParallelTable. That was wrong.

Comment: @Eisbär I don't fully understand your question, but I think it is related to this phenomenon: let's work with `ParallelEvaluate` which (unlike `ParallelTable`) does not automatically distribute definitions.  In a newly started kernel set `a=1;` and try `ParallelEvaluate[a+a]`.  It appears to work, but the calculation wasn't done on the subkernels.  Instead each subkernel returned a symbolic `a+a` to the main kernel, where that expression evaluated further.  Compare `ParallelEvaluate[Print[a+a]]` to `ParallelEvaluate[a+a]`.  Because of this some calculations *appear* to work but are in fact...

Comment: @Eisbär ... done in serial (not parallel) when something goes wrong with distributing the definitions.  Low memory usage indicates that the definitions are not in fact distributed across subkernels.